# Export subset of MySQL database

Tags: mysql

So my client has a database with a minimum of several million entries across several dozen tables. I don't need all of their information, and I don't want it. But, I do need to have data from each of their several dozen tables so that I can test their site locally. What can I do to export, say, the first five rows of every table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found [this blog post](http://www.geeknewz.com/board/index.php?automodule=blog&blogid=76&showentry=434) which suggests the following:

```
mysqldump --opt --where="true LIMIT 100" dbname > dbname.sql
```

Comment: The link is broken :(